# SQL Output as XML stop repeating the namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, ssis

I'm using SSIS\SQL Server 2014 and am using the below SQL statement to output to XML.

In summary, 1 property can have many schedules.  I only want the name space to appear once before the 'Job' XML path, however, if there are multiple schedules, then the namespace is also appearing in the xml output for each schedule - how do I stop this?

My code:

```
DECLARE @XMLOutput XML
DECLARE @XMLOutputChar nvarchar(max)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.example.com' as ns)

SELECT @XMLOutput =
(
SELECT  
ISNULL(T1.[PropertyID],'') as PropertyId,
ISNULL(T1.[Desc],'') as JobDescription,
    (
        SELECT
        ScheduleId as ScheduleId,
        LocationID as LocationId,
        FROM [JobSchedules]
        WHERE T1.JobIdentity = JobIdentity 
        FOR XML PATH('JobSchedules'), TYPE
    )
FROM   [JobFile] T1 


FOR XML PATH('Job'),TYPE,ROOT('JobLoader')
)

SET @XMLOutputChar = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@XMLOutput)

SELECT @XMLOutputChar AS XMLOutput
```

This is the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<JobLoader xmlns="http://www.example.com/" >
<Job>
<PropertyId>PROPERTYID</PropertyId>
<JobDescription>JOBDESCRIPTION</JobDescription>
<JobSchedules>
<JobSchedule>
<ScheduleId>SCHEDULEID</ScheduleId>
<LocationId>LOCATIONID</LocationId>
</JobSchedule>
</JobSchedules>
</Job>
</JobLoader>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If I remember it right, the behaviour has been like this since 2005. From xml perspective, it has no difference. It is annoying for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested I was able to resolve this by adding the below line to replace the value just after the encoding line:

```
SET @XMLOutputChar = REPLACE(@XMLOutputChar,'<JobSchedules xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com/"','<JobSchedules ')
```